# Resolve ambiguity in assignment constructor c++

Tags: c++, g++, llvm, ambiguous

#### Description

I have code that is ambiguous when a certain constructor is present. But, when I comment said constructor out, then the compiler complains that a necessary constructor is missing.

#### Minimum Working Example

```
struct X;

struct E{
    E(const double& r){ /* important protocol stuff */ }
    E(const X&);
};

struct X{
    X(){ /* important init stuff */ }
    ~X(){ /* important delete stuff */ }
    //X(const double& r){ *this=E(r); }  // POSITION 1
    X(const X& x){ /* important init stuff */ *this=x; }
    X(const E& e){ /* important init stuff */ *this=e; }
    const X& operator=(const X& x){ return *this=E(x); }
    const X& operator=(const E& e){ /* important stuff */ return *this; }
};

E::E(const X& x){ /* important protocol stuff */ }

E operator+(const E& x, const E& y){ /* important protocol stuff */ return E(1); }
E operator*(const E& x, const E& y){ /* important protocol stuff */ return E(2); }

int main(){
    X x,y;
    x = 3.0;
    X u = 4.0;  // POSITION 2
    y = x + u * 5.0;
    X z = 6.0 + 7.0 * y;
}
```

With *position 1* commented out, *position 2* throws an error.

With *position 1* included, there is an ambiguity error.

Basically, I want to remove *position 1* and with that double->X be cast via double->E->X.

#### Questions

1. What is the name of the problem?
2. How do I fix it?

#### Things I tried:

- explicit keywords in front of various constructors. For E, this results in errors **after** *position 2*. For X, this results in the same error as with *position 1* commented out.
- removing constructors/operators from the definitions from X,E. This however is no solution, because I need to be able to include some *important stuff*.
- trying different compilers (g++ 8.3.0 and 9.2.0, clang++ 12.0.0). This did not change the issue.

Comment: Please be more specific than "throws an error". Copy and paste the actual error messages.

Comment: There can be only be one user-defined implicit conversion in a chain of implicit conversions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ambiguity occurs because (in the `x = 3.0;` line) the compiler can't decide which of the two assignment operators to use: the one with the `X&` argument or the one with the `E&`, as both parameter types are convertible from the given `double` (because both `E` and `X` have constructors that take a `const double&` parameter).

You can resolve this error by providing a *third* assignment operator, which takes a `const double&` argument, like so:

```cpp
struct X {
    X() { /* important init stuff */ }
    ~X() { /* important delete stuff */ }
    X(const double& r){ *this=E(r); }  // Now uncommented (required)
    X(const X& x) { /* important init stuff */ *this = x; }
    X(const E& e) { /* important init stuff */ *this = e; }
    const X& operator=(const double& x) { return *this = E(x); } // Add this!
    const X& operator=(const X& x) { return *this = E(x); }
    const X& operator=(const E& e) { /* important stuff */ return *this; }
};
```